# Prove that $(1007!)^2 > \binom{2015}{1007}^2$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that $(1007!)^2 > \binom{2015}{1007}^2$.

This is equivalent to proving that $1007! > \binom{2015}{1007}$. We then get this is equivalent to $$(1007!)^2 > \dfrac{2015!}{1008!} = 2015 \cdot 2014 \cdots 1009.$$ How do we show this?

Comment: $n!> \binom{2n+1}{n}$ ?

Comment: Consider $$A_n=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!^2(n+1)!}$$ The goal is to show that $$A_{1007}<1$$ To do so, compute $$A_8=\frac{2431}{4032}<1$$ and note that $$\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=\frac{2(2n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}<1$$ for every $n\geqslant3$. QED.

Comment: @Did What does computing $A_8$ do?

Comment: @Maman Not always: compare $7!=5040$ and ${15\choose7}=6435$.

Comment: @user19405892 It shows that one term of the sequence is $<1$. Then all the terms following it are also $<1$ since the ratios are $<1$.

Comment: @Did So you are saying that $n! > \binom{2n+1}{n}$ for all $n \geq 8$?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 3):

Consider the ratios $$A_n=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!^2(n+1)!}$$ The goal is to show that $$A_{1007}<1$$ To do so, compute $$A_8=\frac{2431}{4032}<1$$ and note that $$\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}=\frac{2(2n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}<1$$ for every $n\geqslant3$ since the difference of the denominator and the numerator is $$n^2-n-4\geqslant(n-3)(n+2)$$ This shows that $$A_n<1$$ for every $n\geqslant8$.

Answer (score 1):

I will follow the comment of Maman (which I thank warmly), the first one that had the idea to show a more general statement: $n!>\binom{2n+1}{n}$.

We show by induction (what else?) that $n!>\binom{2n+1}{n}$ for $n\geq 8$ (8 comes from this evaluation [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n!-binomial(2n%2B1,n),%20n%3D1..10)).

For $n=8$ it is ok. Inductive step. For $n\geq 8$,
$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!>(n+1)\binom{2n+1}{n}\stackrel{?}{\geq}\binom{2n+3}{n+1}.$$
So we have to verify that
$$\frac{(2n+1)!}{n! n!}\geq \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)! (n+2)!},$$
that is
$$(n+1)^2(n+2)\geq (2n+3)(2n+2)$$
which holds for $n\geq 8$.

Comment: The hint does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: Cite your source?

Comment: @Did I think you should post your answer instead of a comment. I would upvote it.

Comment: @Did I followed Maman's suggestion. I note that your solution is similar.
Why don't you post your answer instead of a comment?

Comment: "I followed Maman's suggestion" Actually you did not. "I note that your solution is similar" ?? Odd behaviour.

Comment: @Did Maman comment (it appeared before than your commnet) suggests to prove a statement which depends on $n$. Induction is the first method to try? Don't you think that it is plausible?

Comment: No. (And I will not comment further on, you know what you did.)

Answer (score -1):

You get $(1007!)^2$ compared to $\frac{2015!}{1008!}$.  The second expression is a product of $1007$ integers.  The first expression is the product of $2014$ integers.  If you take them in carefully chosen pairs, you can have the product of each pair greater than each factor in the second expression.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But how come it doesn't work for, say, $n \le 6$? (I haven't checked higher $n$.)

Comment: " in carefully chosen pairs" Carefully chosen how?

Comment: $2\cdot 1008$, $3\cdot 1009$, etc. are each bigger than any factor in $2015!/1008!$.  So that's most of it.  In fact they are plenty bigger.  The two end points don't quite do it, but there is "plenty" of overage in the other pairs to take care of the shortage in $1\cdot 1007$ and $1007\cdot 1$. Just borrow a couple 2's from some even factors in the middle.